# Analytical Methods for mapping a disc to its inner square

Tags: geometry

In the publications [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344),[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07875) of Chamberlain Fong several analytical, non-conformal methods were derived for squaring the disk. All methods map a disc with an radius r to its outer square with the side length of 2*r. Are there analogue methods known to map a disc to its inner square?

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344): https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344 Chamberlain Fong: Analytical Methods for Squaring the Disc. 2015.

[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07875): https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07875 Chamberlain Fong: Elliptification of Rectangular Imagery. 2019.

Comment: The size of the square doesn't matter much. You can always scale everything with a map like $z\mapsto rz$ for some real number $r$.

Comment: @egorovik: In our disc2sq implementation are massive stretching artifacts at the corners that are not viewable in the images Fong published whereas sq2disc is fine using squeezing. The idea was to reduce disc2sq also to a squeezing process therefore disc2inner_sq.